No transferrable DOT in my account while I should do
My account shows 0 DOT transferrable on subscan but has 243.2 free by querying system.account on pjs
I tried sending 5 DOT to the address, assuming the 5 DOT would appear in transferrable but for some reason transferrable is still 0 after the transfer.
Here's the tx of the 5 DOT transfer:
https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/21182496-3
That's my wallet address: https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/14wNsw7P85nZj4CnvVkMJCH2mGsaSDcx67gK6Acs8UZN1sZL?tab=transfer
The talisman team have searched a bit and so far didn't find the issue.
To help the process, here are their thoughts:




Any idea why this is happening?
Thank you!

This may be related to https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/issues/328.
There has been a change in the method for calculating transferable balances.
